# 16-byte aligned matrix in DirectX9 and D3DX with Havok Physics 2012

Tags: matrix, directx9, havok, simd

I want to ask a question about `D3DXMATRIX` and `D3DXMATRIXA16`, and how to use them with Havok Physics.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

I successfully created an instance of `hkpWorld`, added an `hkpRigidbody` instance with `hkpSphereShape`.

The class representing the sphere object has:

```
hkpRigidBody m_RigidBody;  // Rigidbody
D3DXMATRIX m_Transform;    // Rendering matrix
```

Judging from the values of `m_RigidBody->getPosition()`, the simulation is running without problem.
So now obviously I want to render the sphere according to its position and orientation calculated by havok.

This is how I tried to extract the matrix for rendering:

```
const hkTransform& t = m_RigidBody->getTransform();
t.get4x4ColumnMajor(&m_Transform._11);
```

Then I happily ran the program, which would break in `get4x4ColumnMajor` and give me this message through my error report function:

> C:\NightlyJobs\09-07-Sun-01\Source\Common/Base/Math/Vector/Sse/hkSseVector4.inl(
>   1831): [0x64211C2F] Assert: pointer must be aligned for SIMD.

I took this to mean that the matrix had to be 16-byte aligned, so I changed

```
D3DXMATRIX m_Transform;
```

to

```
D3DXMATRIXA16 m_Transform;
```

This time, the problem is still there **but isn't 100% reproducible**.
Sometimes it runs without problem, sometimes `get4x4ColumnMajor` fails with above message.

Changing the matrix declaration to

```
_declspec(align(16)) D3DXMATRIX m_Transform;
```

did not help either.

So, to summarize my question:

- How would I go about extracting the matrix suitable for rendering with DirectX9?
- Why do `D3DXMATRIXA16` and `_declspec(align(16))` seem to be inconsistent about being 16-byte aligned or not, every time I run the program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to remember is that `_declspec(align(16))` only affects the struct/class layout, is respected for local or global variables, but *has no affect on heap allocated memory*.

In other words, it doesn't matter if the member variable of a class is marked with alignment if the class is allocated with `new`. Heap allocations by default with x86 (32-bit) are only 8-byte aligned, so you have a 50/50 shot of getting the required alignment that way. By default x64 native (64-bit) alignment is 16-byte.

Otherwise you need to make use of `_aligned_malloc` to get other alignment behavior from heap allocation. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418732(v=vs.85).aspx#Properly_Align_Alloc) for some more notes on this.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking into _aligned_malloc you suggested, along with placement new :)